# Могу ли я использовать Docker CE в комерческом проекте?

Tags: docker

Могу ли я использовать Docker CE в комерческом проекте или надо покупать лицензию на EE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Лицензия Apache](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/LICENSE) даёт пользователю право использовать программное обеспечение для любых целей, свободно изменять и распространять изменённые копии, за исключением названия.

Данная лицензия не ставит условием неизменность лицензии распространения программного обеспечения, и не настаивает даже на сохранении его бесплатного и открытого статуса. Единственным условием, накладываемым лицензией Apache, является информирование получателя о факте использования исходного кода.

Comment: Грубо говоря если я разворачиваю частный софт компании docker ce то ничего по ап я не нарушаю просто довольно расплывчато пишут на сайте

Comment: @hi-tech никаких проблем.